# CakePHP OR condition not properly working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have the following problem: I have a table for customers, with a prename and a name. Now I have variable keywords (in this example hardcoded 2) in an array and I want to check whether one of the keywords match with either the name OR the prename. So I figured to use the OR condition in the following codesnippet. Unfortunately it doesnt provide the wanted output:

```
$searchValueArr = ["keyword1","keyword2"];
$customers = $customersTable->find()
->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) {
    $orConditions = $exp->or_(function ($or) {
        foreach($searchValueArr as $searchValue) {
            $or = $or
            ->eq('prename LIKE', "%".$searchValue."%")
            ->eq('name LIKE', "%".$searchValue."%");
        }
        return $or;
    });
    return $orConditions;
})
->all();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list `$searchValueArr` in the `use` part of each anonymous function, otherwise it's not in context, ex:

```
$searchValueArr = ["keyword1","keyword2"];
$customers = $customersTable->find()
    ->where(function (QueryExpression $exp) use ($searchValueArr){
        $orConditions = $exp->or_(function ($or) use ($searchValueArr){
            foreach($searchValueArr as $searchValue) {
                $or = $or
                    ->eq('prename LIKE', "%".$searchValue."%")
                    ->eq('name LIKE', "%".$searchValue."%");
            }
            return $or;
        });
        return $orConditions;
    })
    ->all();
```

Also this is personal preference really, but you technically can still use array formatting for a query like this (a nested set of OR's), for example:

```
$searchValueArr = ["keyword1","keyword2"];
$searchTerms = [];
foreach($searchValueArr as $searchValue) {
    $searchTerms[] = [
        'OR' => [
            'prename LIKE' => "%".$searchValue."%",
            'name LIKE' => "%".$searchValue."%"
        ]
    ];
}
$customers = $customersTable->find()
    ->where([
        'OR' => $searchTerms
    ])
    ->all();
```